# "The clubs and societies enjoy boom."

Tags: grammaticality

"The clubs and societies enjoy boom." The meaning intended to convey is that the various clubs and societies organized in the universities are flourishing. The word "boom" can be used like this "there is a boom in something". Since "there is" to a certain extent indicates "having", so is this appropriate?

Comment: Please edit the question to better explain what you mean and what your question is.  Are you asking about "boom", "there is" or something else?

Comment: What does "sth" mean?

Comment: @Mark: something.

Comment: @IVY: "sth" is not a well-known contraction of "something".  I don't recommend you use it when writing for a general audience.

Comment: @chaos: "sth" seems to be fairly well established usage on ELU (some dictionaries also use it).

Answer (score 2):

That sentence is barely comprehensible, though "Clubs and societies enjoy boom" is consistent with the telegraphic style typical of English-language newspaper headlines.  Outside of that context, you should say "The clubs and societies are enjoying a boom."